# IBM Watson: Missing or invalid for server-side CloudFunctions action call

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I went to the Functions/API Key to retrieve the user&password, but I still receive this error:

> **Dialog node error**
>
> Mandatory action property "credentials" missing or
> invalid for server-side CloudFunctions action call. The value must be
> a string that references a variable such as "$my_creds" that expands
> to an object like {"user":"..", "password":".."}. Dialog node:
> [GetProducts]

Any ideas why?

```
// IBM WATSON Dialog: 
// Dialog Node Name: GetProducts

// JSON Editor:

{
  "context": {
    "private": {
      "my_creds": {
        "user": "*********",
        "password:": "*********"
      }
    }
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Product :  "<?entities.products[0].literal?>"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "/*****@gmail.com_dev/getProducts2",
      "type": "server",
      "parameters": {
        "url": "<?entities.products[0].literal?>"
      },
      "credentials": "$private.my_creds",
      "result_variable": "context.result"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The credentials need to be present when that dialog node is processed. The context section defines what will be present at the end of that processing. Thus, the credentials are not known to the action.

My advise is to NOT store the credentials in the workspace. This is a security issue and bad practice, even for testing. Follow the [example in the Watson Assistant documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#create-action). It has instructions on how to add the credentials to the "Try it out" panel. For production, pass in the credentials from the app or middleware. Here are [some](http://blog.4loeser.net/2018/06/use-botkit-middleware-to-create-watson.html) examples on how [that](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/02/serverless-security-credentials-tutorial/) can be done.